# UICollectionViewTransitionLayout - mimicking iOS7 photos collectionview layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm reading Apples [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/ContentViews.html) on [animating changes in a collection view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013096), trying to imitate the photos app. When choosing an image, the image "grows" from the area it is located in the collectionview to a full size view.

Apple notes using a `UICollectionViewLayout` object but for me it is looking very messy and also the final image in the full size gallery isn't visible, as the animation is centered on the collectionview.

My code is as follows

```
-(void)setHorizontalLayout:(BOOL)layout
{
    if (layout == YES)
    {


        UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *layout =[self.collectionView startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:[self getHorizontalPagingLayout] completion:^(BOOL completed, BOOL finish) {
            [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        }];

        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        layout.transitionProgress = 0.1;
        double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self updateLayout:layout];
            //[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
            //[self.collectionView finishInteractiveTransition];

        });
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        return;
}
}

-(void)updateLayout:(UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)layout
{
    if (layout.transitionProgress >= 1.0)
    {

        [self.collectionView finishInteractiveTransition];
        return;
    }
    double delayInSeconds = 0.05;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        layout.transitionProgress += 0.005;
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        [self updateLayout:layout];
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about presenting an UIViewController with an UIImageView using a custom transition?  This tutorial helped me.

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

I know that Photos actually use the layout to layout navigation transition on UICollectionViewController (`useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` to achieve the animation when going from moments to years etc (Session 218 in 2013 if I'm not mistaken)

That being said things get really interesting when you attempt to craft transitions between collection views with different data sources. The chaps at [Objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html) wrote a beautiful piece on this.

However, if you are looking to implement the pinch to open effect its actually far simpler than it seems.

In a nutshell lets assume we simply want to animate a cell from the collection view to expand into a full screen view controller. In that instance all you need to do is implement a custom viewcontroller transition where you effectively apply a transform to the FullScreenPhotosViewController to make it start at the point of the cell. Then we simply animate the transform to full screen.

Once you have that working its time to make it interactive, the trick in this step is to hide the collection view cell as you start the transition as you want to animate the full screen controller and not the cell (if you don't hide it then the cell will still be visible and it will look confusing). So basically the cell that you now hold under your fingers is actually the FullScreenPhotosViewController with your pinch driving the transform and the original cell is hidden. As you expand the controller you update the percent complete so that the navigation bar updates alongside the transition.

If you want more detail I can include how you can calculate the transforms etc when I get to a computer?